# Selenium input text not working in JSF

Tags: jsf, selenium, jsf-2

I have some page in JSF2.0 where I need to validate fields. This is cross-field validation, so I binded fields to UIComponents. All three fields are `<h:inputText>` so all are binded to `HtmlInputText`.

Validation method just reads values from all the `HtmlInputText`s. It works pretty well when I run the app and use it by hand. Problem is it doesn't work when selenium inputs values. Part of selenium code is:

```
selenium.type("identifier=myForm:myTextField", "someText");
```

So it inputs text into the text field. It works and I can see text is really there. But when I debug validation method, which reads values from UIComponents, the value is `null` after clicking "Submit". It is not `null` when entered by hand, only when selenium enters it.

Why is that? Why selenium doesn't work? It does pretty the same I do by hand, yet it works by hand, doesn't work by selenium.

Comment: I have never had problems with Selenium like that. You seem to be suggesting that this is specific to components which use `binding`. So, binding-less input fields do just work? Are the model values anyway updated? Is the bean action method invoked? Is there some `f:ajax` involvement? Anyway, the smallest possible excerpt of your `<h:form>`, the relevant managed bean code and the generated JUnit/TestNG `@Test` method would be helpful so that we can try to reproduce the problem and/or spot the error better.

Comment: Thank you @BalusC. I found the problem, and it is described in my next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439716/ The problem was when hidden field was in the page before fields I want to validate.

Comment: How exactly is this an issue for selenium? Is this hidden field filled by JS?

Answer (score 0):

Note that JSF-generated IDs are usually not the ID you have assigned. For example `myTextField` in a form called `myForm` will have an ID `myForm:myTextField`

Comment: I have taken it into account. Maybe I simplified my example too much, there should be something like "form:myTextField". Anyway it works. I can see in browser started by selenium that the text is filled in.

Answer (score 0):

As JSF takes charge of ID's I prefer setting an 'unique id' in the `styleClass` attribute which is rendered as `class`. Then you select the input with that class.

You may have more than the 'unique id' on an element. Then I prefer to search for an element with a class that contains the 'unique id'. It lets you change styling without changing the test.